# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having a slight issue with some code that I have written, I keep getting the error:

> expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

I have commented where the error is happening. Not sure what the issue is however. Code is as follows:

```
renderBody() {
    const { bookings } = this.props;
    if (bookings.length > 0) {
        return (
            Object.keys(bookings).map(e => (
                <TableBody>
                    {Object.values(bookings[e]).forEach((value) => {
                        <TableCell>{value}</TableCell>; //<-ERROR??
                    })}
                </TableBody>
            ))
        );
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Are you using curlys there where you should be using parenths to return implicitly?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Maybe not supporting a destructuring assignment? Try removing `const {bookings}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are not doing anything inside `forEach` (no assignment, no calculation), also `forEach` will not return anything, use `map` to return the TableCell for each array entry.

`Eslint` will throw an error, if you write a `forEach` loop without any operation.

Write it like this:

```
{Object.values(bookings[e]).map(value => (
    <TableCell>{value}</TableCell>
))}
```

Comment: While that's true, it's not clear to me that it would result in the error the OP reports.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, i think, that its a linting error *expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression*

Comment: @MayankShukla the code snippet causes a parsing error. See updated comment to original question

Comment: @MubeenHussain because you forgot to close the `(`, here: `)}
            </TableBody>`, use this: `))}
            </TableBody>` closing of brace in nested map.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing a closing `)` :

```
 Object.values(bookings[e]).map(value => (
            <TableCell>{value}</TableCell>
  ))} // <--
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use normal for loop instead of map or forEach if you want to process some data inside the loop.

If you are returning an HTML content then you should explicitly return it.

```
Object.keys(bookings).map(e => {
    return (
        <TableBody>
            {Object.values(bookings[e]).forEach((value) => {
                return (
                    <TableCell>{value}</TableCell>
                )
            })}
        </TableBody>
    )
})
```